# How do I write a code to make a function run randomly every 10 minutes in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron

Suppose, right now it is 1:04 PM. First, 10 mins slot is 1:04 PM to 1:14 PM, the screenshot will be taken at any time randomly between 1:04 PM and 1:14 PM and once we reach 1:14 PM a new slot is from 1:14 PM to 1:24 PM and a random screenshot is taken between 1:14 PM and 1:24 PM. How do I achieve this, I am a beginner and struggling to build the logic required.

I want to make changes to setTimeout to make it execute randomly any time in a span of 10 minutes, just like how Upwork screen tracker works.

Here is my code.

```
const uploadFiles = (img) => {
 // logic
const storageRef = ref(storage, 
 `/screenshots/${uuidv4()}`);

uploadString(storageRef, img, 
 "data_url").then((snapshot) => {
   console.log("Uploaded a data_url string!");
 });
};
let newTimeoutId;
const screenshot = async () => {
    setTimeoutId(true);

const newTimeoutId = setTimeout(async () => {
  const screenshotData = await 
  ipcRenderer.invoke("capture");

const string = new 
 Buffer.from(screenshotData).toString("base64");

const img = `data:image/png;base64,${string}`;
  console.log(img);
  uploadFiles(img);
  screenshot();
 }, 600000);
};

const stopScreenshot = () => {
    setTimeoutId(false);
    clearTimeout(newTimeoutId);
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

This should give an idea of one possible way to achieve what is desired:

Execute a function / logic at one random time, within every 10 minutes.

**Code Snippet**

```js
let stopAt = 15; // for testing, setting a maximum of 15 iterations
let maxRandomDelay = 1000; // max 1 second delay for testing
// for 10 minutes, make it 10 * 60 * 1000
const resDiv = document.getElementById("rd");
resDiv.innerText = 'display at random intervals: ';

const delay = async(ms) => new Promise(res => setTimeout(() => { res(ms); }, ms));

const myTimer = () => {
  delay(Math.floor(Math.random() * maxRandomDelay))
  .then((r) => {
    resDiv.innerText += `\n..${stopAt} (random-wait: ${r} ms).. `;
    // instead of the above line, invoke your desired function here
  }).then(() => {
    if (stopAt-- > 0) myTimer();
  })
};

myTimer();
```

```html
<div id="rd" />
```

Comment: Thank you for making me understand the logic behind it. Your code snippet was really helpful.

Comment: Glad to be of assistance. :-). Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) (you get a badge!), read through the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). And, also please consider: [What to do when my question is answered?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

i am also really new to js, but maybe you could use Math.random.

something like this?:

Math.floor((Math.random() * 600000) + 1);

it returns a number between 1 and 600000

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).